# What was the link to the iOS App Store story on selected apps from WWDC18 Scholars?

Tags: ios-appstore

I recall that there was an App Store story on selected apps from WWDC18 scholars, but I forgot to save the link before the App Store updated. Does any one still have the link to that story, and would be willing to share it here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Congratulations to the WWDC18 Scholarship Winners**
>
> WWDC18 Scholarships reward talented students and active members of organisations that promote science, technology, engineering or maths, with the opportunity to attend Apple's […]

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/story/id1384637708

Comment: Thanks man! Really appreciate it! By the way, is there a way to manually search for it?

Comment: I Googled ‘app store today wwdc 2018 scholars apps’ and the first result was a 9to5Mac blog post with that link, perhaps someone should make a website for these!

Comment: that’s a great idea! It’s time there’s a complete catalog of App Store stories.