# See history of Today tab iOS App Store

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

On iOS 12, the App Store contains a ["Today" tab](https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/), showing curated apps:

[image]

Some days ago, they showed a beautiful game, that I would *love* to download.

Unfortunately, I cannot find it anymore, since I found no way of getting to the "Today" tab of past days.

**My question:**

Is it possible to show the content of the iOS 12 "Today" tab of previous days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related: [iOS - App Store Stories](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327613/ios-app-store-stories/349131#349131)

The maximum you can look back for is 7 days. There is a website called [Sensor Tower](https://sensortower.com/featured/today) which lets you see up to 365 days but it requires a subscription.

Alternatively, for some stories, you can tap on the Share Story button shown at bottom, copy the link and send it to yourself. However, this approach is highly manual, would have required following it since the day App Store redesign was publicly launched. Also, it is not possible to do so if you want to start out today as the older feed entries can no longer be accessed

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as that iirc that part of iOS's app store is a WebKit based thing, probably not. Though you may look under top charts under free as it may be on the top charts list. (Your mileage may vary this is based on my iPhone 4s which is running 7.1.2)

Answer (score 0):

I tried asking a few reps from Apple tech support if they had a way to provide me a share link from a recent date and/or if they had a "Today" story history or archive they could search.  They all told me no, it's not accessible to them, and not available to the public from what they are able to gather.  It seems very odd considering these are all are available within some parent folder as shown from the links below, and it's a waste of promotional resources by not allowing customers to search previous dates for curated apps.

If you know part of the title it should show up in the search results as a story.  For ex, these showed up for me when I searched for them using the Search tab:

https://apps.apple.com/us/story/id1410000361

https://apps.apple.com/us/story/id1348055525